# If there are some identical row names in Table1 and Table2 table then how to read them in java?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

If there are some identical row names in Table1 and Table2 table then how to read them in java?
Currently, for reading the column values I use table1.coulmn_name. But it will only return the Table1 column value.

```
Table1 executeQuery(String billId)
    {
        ResultSetHandler<Table1> resultHandler = new BeanHandler<Table1>(Table1.class)       
        table1 table1 = run.query("SELECT * FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.payment_id =Table2.payment_id WHERE Table1.bill_id="+billId, resultHandler)

        return table1
    }
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And read [mcve].

Comment: Ever tried table2.column_name?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: please do not concatenate parameters to your SQL string like that. Learn how to properly use a `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 1):

You mean identical *column* names.  Rows don't have names in SQL.

A best practice is to list the columns you want instead of using `select *`:

```
select t1.col1, t2.col2, . . .
```

If two columns have the same name, use `as` to assign a new name:

select t1.col1, t2.col1 as t2_col1, . . .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index of the column. For example:

```
ResultSet rs = ...
while (rs.next) {
  int ida = rs.getInt(1); // id from Table1 in column #1
  int idb = rs.getInt(2); // id from Table2 in column #2
}
```